# Duplicate Row Value to Next Null Rows

Tags: python, pandas

How can I duplicate Values from the Group column until the next row is not null?
Example:

```
Group     Value
A         1
NULL      2    
NULL      3
NULL      4
B         5
NULL      6
NULL      7
```

Expected Result:

```
Group     Value
A         1
A         2    
A         3
A         4
B         5
B         6
B         7
```

Comment: `df.ffill()`???

Comment: Thanks for helping a beginner in Python like me. Really appreciate it.